# phalcon router not working

Tags: php, url-routing, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I try to use a router with phalcon. This is how it is included in index.php right after registering the 'events manager':

```
$di->set('router', function(){
    require __DIR__.'/../app/config/routes.php';
    return $router;
});
```

and this is how the routes.php looks like:

```
<?php
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

$router->add("/", array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->add("/topics", array(
    'controller' => 'wurst',
    'action' => 'index'
));

$router->handle();
return $router;
```

The website reacts as if the router was not existent. /topics and topics say this:

```
TopicsController handler class cannot be loaded
```

and I also cannot use a die("test"); function inside routes.php . nothing happens.
I also tried to activate it without a separate file, but the result was the same :(

(The sample web-application INVO was used as starting point for my site )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it seems to work:

```
Action 'route404' was not found on handler 'index'
```

the problem was , that I put the function to set the router in index.php *within* "set dispatcher function". ..did not see the closing braces.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, can you mark is as accepted, it'd help keep things organised,  thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

`$router->setUriSource(Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);`  will use default $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Aw yeah, how did you know that? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your index/index action is working when you access domain.com/index.php, check that you are  using proper uri source, if using nginx or php built-in server you might have some problems with routing and $_GET['_uri'] which phalcon use for handling uris.

can find more about it on phalcon router documentation about uri sources -> http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html#uri-sources

Comment: the index action is working when accessing /index.php, but where do I set the uri source? In routes.php it is not possible. It seems that the 'standard-routing' of phalcon is still active (/:controller/:action/:parameter) and my routes.php is not recognized at all. i cannot do a `die(var_dump($router));` inside routes.php - nothing happens. (server is apache)